# PHP Time Problem

Tags: php, mysql

well, I"ve got a time format of the type: 2011-02-16T01:25:50+04:00

I want to strip the +04:00 from the end of the string.  How to do it?

I am converting a timestamp from mysql to ISO 8601 format using this function:

```
$timeagotime = date('c',strtotime($row['created_at']));
```

where $timeagotime contains the value: 2011-02-16T01:25:50+04:00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to the documentation for php's `date` function:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You need to use a different format string.  For instance,

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['created_at']));
```

Givens you "2011-02-16".  There are a number of format strings... check out the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substr()` to remove it, or just generate a date without it in the first place, though you couldn't use the 'c' formatting option, since that'd just add the timezone on again.

```
$timeagotime = substr($timeagotime, 0, 19)

$timeagotime = date('Y-m-dTG:i:s', strtotime(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely don't need the end then you can use the following. Otherwise I'd suggest using a different way to generate your date from the table. [PHP Date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

`$timeagotime = substr(date('c',strtotime($row['created_at'])), 0, 19);`